# Tailwindcss prettier plugin only affects css files

Tags: ember.js, tailwind-css, prettier

Ive installed the `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` in my emberjs app. It runs and sorts the classes in my css files correctly but it doesnt touch the handlebars files. The standard prettier stuff still works in the handlebar files.

Ive tried adding a `twConfig` to the `.prettierrc` as suggested in the [docs](https://github.com/tqwewe/prettier-plugin-tailwind/blob/master/OPTIONS.md#twconfig) but that was unrecognised.

I'd really like to use this plugin but I need to support the handlebars files. Please let me know if anyone has any ideas on how I could solve this.

Here's my current prettierrc.yaml

```
# We use pretty much all defaults from Prettier https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html
# We prefer single quotes to align with our internal RECONZ styleguide
singleQuote: true
twConfig: 'app/tailwind/config.js' // adding this throws this error below
// [warn] Ignored unknown option { twConfig: "app/tailwind/config.js" }.
overrides:
  - files: '*.hbs'
    options:
      parser: 'glimmer'
      # The Ember community uses single quotes in JS & double in templates
      singleQuote: false
```

These are the versions I have installed:

```
"prettier": "^2.6.0",
"prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.11",
yarn: v1.22.17
```

**UPDATE**: the issue seems to be the parser which is set to `glimmer` When I tried with `html` instead the plugin worked but unfortunately I need to keep the parser as `glimmer` because `html` also causes some unwanted effects. Is there another option I could use?

Comment: can you post your .prettierrc?

Comment: Sure, added to the question description.

Comment: Can you also post the error you received and the .prettierrc with the tailwind config that gave the error?

Comment: Thanks, Ive posted it to the description. I get the same warning if `twConfig` is an empty string.

Comment: can you add your versions of prettier, the plugin, and what package manager (and version) you're using as well?

Comment: also, have you seen this: https://github.com/tqwewe/prettier-plugin-tailwind/issues/52

Looks like this is the plugin that should be used as it is maintained by the tailwind team

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I am using the official Tailwind Prettier plugin. I'll update the description now.

Comment: For anyone else interested there is a discussion underway with the team here https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/discussions/8671